# Transcribing pronunciations

Tags: transcription

If someone writes that, e.g. בּ is pronounced "b" and צירי is pronounced "ie," can we say that they write that בֵּ is pronounced "bie"? I'm writing about Hebrew here but this could apply to any language that doesn't use the Latin alphabet.

Comment: _Pronounced "ie"_ is not a very clear description of what the pronunciation is. How is "i" pronounced? Is the _someone_ who wrote that a native speaker of Hebrew? Are you using Modern Hebrew phonemes?  If so, you shouldn't use quotes, but rather /slæʃəz/ to mark pronunciations. If you're not, then who are you writing for and why not use phonemes?

Comment: אני לא מבין את השאלה שלך

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not specifically asking about a particular sequence of letters in Modern Hebrew, the answer is, "No, you cannot safely say that". That may actually be a usually false statement, or a misleading one, since it is untrue in Spanish (as an example) that the letter *g* is pronounced "g": instead, it is pronounced at least as [g, γ, x], depending on context. Any such statement would also need to distinguish the letter used in the spelling system from the actual pronunciation, notated in some language-independent transcriptional system. It is true that in Albanian, Somali, Menomini, Zulu and Chinese "q" is pronounced as "q", but the phonetic value of the letter "q" is not the same.

Comment: I'm not talking about the actual sounds, just how they're transliterated/transcribed. I would also take different sounds attached to a foreign grapheme into account when working with this – there just doesn't happen to be one in this case. I'm also talking about Polish Ashkenazi Hebrew, not Modern Hebrew.